# Sas(not mini) to Sata cable

Tags: raid, sata, sas

I've been thinking of getting a [Dell SAS card](http://cgi.ebay.com/Dell-P-N-0HN359-SAS-5-PCIE-Adapter-Card-USC-51-MY412_W0QQitemZ320466958648QQcmdZViewItemQQptZLH_DefaultDomain_0?hash=item4a9d51b938) to use in a server and I understand that normal SATA drivers are usable. Seeing that these Dell cards don't have mini-SAS, what sort of cable do I need to connect normal SATA drives to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct cable is " SAS Controller 32-Pin to 4 x SATA Hard Disk HDD Converter Cable ".

Comment: Specifically, one with SFF-8484 type parent connectors.